# Join a table with appended letter - MYSQL

Tags: mysql, join

I have 2 tables that are uneditable by me.

1st table has values like this:

```
11111
11112
11113
11114
```

2nd table has values like this:

```
S11111
S11112
S11113
S11114
```

---

How can I do a join using these keys without editing either table at all?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `CONCAT()` in your joining condition.

```
ON t2.value = CONCAT('S', t1.value)
```